# Nmap incredibly slow on my router

Tags: networking, router, nmap

I'm attempting to use nmap on my Tomato router (Linux 2.6) to do a quick survey of a particular subnet on my LAN. Even when I set it to scan a single client it takes close to four minutes to complete. Based on the debugging output I can see that the scan itself is extremely quick, but the total time is... not.

Here's the command I'm using (for testing only):

```
nmap -d -n -sn -vv 1.1.2.7
```

And here is the output:

```
Starting Nmap 5.35DC1 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-17 21:37 CEST 
--------------- Timing report --------------- 
  hostgroups: min 1, max 100000 
  rtt-timeouts: init 1000, min 100, max 10000 
  max-scan-delay: TCP 1000, UDP 1000, SCTP 1000 
  parallelism: min 0, max 0 
  max-retries: 10, host-timeout: 0 
  min-rate: 0, max-rate: 0 
--------------------------------------------- 
Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 21:37
Scanning 1.1.2.7 [1 port] 
Packet capture filter (device br1): arp and arp[18:4] = 0x08606EBA and arp[22:2] = 0x3D18 
Completed ARP Ping Scan at 21:37, 0.15s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Overall sending rates: 6.73 packets / s, 282.53 bytes / s. 
Nmap scan report for 1.1.2.7 
Host is up, received arp-response (0.087s latency). 
MAC Address: XX:XX:XX:E8:53:2D (Unknown) 
Final times for host: srtt: 86931 rttvar: 86931  to: 434655 
Read from /opt/share/nmap: nmap-mac-prefixes nmap-payloads. 
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 235.73 seconds 
           Raw packets sent: 1 (28B) | Rcvd: 1 (28B)
```

As you can see, the ping scan completes in no time, but the total time is 235s. I believe it attempts to match the OUI of the MAC address using nmap-mac-prefixes, but I can't imagine that taking so long.

I've tried all sorts of options to no avail. Any idea where the delay is coming from?

Comment: worth trying also on the nmap mailing list

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the slowdown is, but the standard Nmap debugging advice surely applies:

1. Update your Nmap. Version 5.35DC1 was released in 2010, 4 years ago. For an actively developed project like Nmap, that's ancient history. Try the latest version (6.47 at the time of this writing) at http://nmap.org/download.html
2. Increase debug level. You will get more verbose output as you add `-d` arguments. For most purposes, `-d3` is the most that you will need.
3. If the problem persists, file a bug report to dev@nmap.org with the output of:

   - `nmap --version`
   - `nmap --iflist`
   - The command causing problems (including *where* in the output the hang occurs, if possible)

One final note: Since you are running Nmap on an embedded system, it's entirely possible that processing and file access times will be much slower than on a general purpose computer.

Comment: Nmap was installed via Optware and that is apparently the latest version it has. I'm not sure how to (or if I can) update the version, but I'll look into it. Good info, thanks.